# Replace all certain character except first occurrence in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**Example**

- Input  = 1.1.0.1
- Expected output = 1.101

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could make use **[substr()](http://php.net/substr)** and **[str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)** fairly easily:

```
$str = '1.1.0.1';
$pos = strpos($str,'.');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $str = substr($str,0,$pos+1) . str_replace('.','',substr($str,$pos+1));
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$s = preg_replace('/((?<=\.)[^.]*)\./', '$1', $s);
```

Matches zero or more non-dot characters followed by a dot, but only if the match was preceded by a dot.  This prevents a match on the initial digit(s).  Replaces the match with only the non-dot characters (the digits), which were captured in group #1.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Fixed.  I probably just tossed that off because the non-regex answer had already been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$input="1.1.1.1";
$s = explode(".",$input ) ;
$t=array_slice($s, 1);
print implode(".",array($s[0] , implode("",$t)) );
```

or

```
$input="1.1.1.1";
$s = explode(".",$input ,2) ;
$s[1]=str_replace(".","",$s[1]);
print implode(".",array($s[0] ,$s[1] ) );
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  No `array_splice()`?  `implode()` doesn't need empty glue to be declared -- it is the default.

Answer (score 1):

1. Match&Release the first occurring literal dot
2. Replace all subsequent literal dots

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BZK03))

```
echo preg_replace('~^[^.]*\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.~', '', $string);
// 1.101
```

Or with the "continue" character (`\G`), consume and forget the first literal dot, then replace all subsequent literal dots.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8rd7p))

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:^[^.]*\.|\G(?!^))[^.]*\K\.~', '', $string);
// 1.101
```

Or simply check that a literal dot has a literal dot occurring earlier in the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aQZMP))

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\.)[^.]*\K\.~', '', $string);
// 1.101
```

Answer (score 0):

I though `substr_replace()` would work here, but sadly no... Here is a regex approach:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(\d+\.)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)~', '$1$2$3$4', $str);
```

Comment: This answer is tightly bound to the OP's formatted string and will not be useful as a general purpose technique.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex matches can be clearer by depicting the desired result and avoids the error-prone approach of calls to `substr` and `strpos`. Here I assume that no text is required before the first dot, *i.e.*, that an input may begin with a dot that must be preserved. The difference is whether a quantifier of `*` or `+` is appropriate in the patterns below.

If your inputs will always be short, a straightforward approach is to replace trailing dots until none remain:

```php
$count = 0;
$output = $input;
do {
    $output = preg_replace('/^(.*\.)(.+)\./', '$1$2', $output, -1, $count);
} while ($count != 0);
echo $output;
```

To do it with a single regex match, use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to apply a function ([`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in this case) to the backreference variable `$2`.

```php
$output = preg_replace_callback(
  '/^([^.]*\.)(.+)$/',
  function ($m) { return $m[1] . str_replace('.', '', $m[2]); },
  $input);
```

Sample results:

```
1.1.0.1 - 1.101
.1.0.1  - .101
111     - 111
1.1     - 1.1
1.      - 1.
.1      - .1
.1.     - .1
....    - .
```

You may want to experiment with the code and test cases at [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##NU6xboMwFNz9FU8Rke2UPOouHUjK0qVLl3ZLSEQsE6yAsYxRh4pvpy8ifdLppLunu/ONn3eFbzz7aWxrQCTW@THCHmKwnaivJg7i6/v941NKCb9z0o9x8X0w13Mwvq20OeuqbS@VvgkGwLOTOJyw3BxRCnySScZTkuvR6Wh7RxUdJUEwcQwOku6gSkAYYvhPExx5CpxA5kspc5juAcsymc9A3dbFWqzW29cBtrAejm6VPh6Il40yZxMr3maFCp9RsQcpRbgzskVkSPcH)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the below regex with `s` switch,

```
<?php
$string = '1.1.0.1';
$pattern = "/(?s)((?<=\.).*?)(\.)/i";
$replacement = "$1";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
1.101
```

Comment: Which letter in the pattern is supposed to be affected by the case-insensitive pattern modifier?